# como hacer select de un SQL server 2008r2 solo en el segundo registro?

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo estos registros de ejemplo

```
CREATE TABLE Corredores Row int, Usuario varchar (20), Lugar INT;

+---+-------+-----+
|row|Usuario|lugar|
+---+-------+-----+
| 1 | Jose  |  4  |
+---+-------+-----+
| 2 | carlos|  5  |
+---+-------+-----+
| 3 |fulanit|  7  |
+---+-------+-----+
```

Quiero solo me salga el registro de carlos ejemplo pero sin el JOSE

resultado:

```
+---+-------+-----+
|row|Usuario|lugar|
+---+-------+-----+
| 2 | carlos|  5  |
+---+-------+-----+
```

Con esto no me servira:

```
SELECT TOP 2 * FROM Corredores ORDER BY row desc
```

ya que me salgra OTRO registro el de Jose

Comment: Necesitas explicarnos más sobre el criterio para filtrar la búsqueda. Con lo que nos has contado hasta ahora, bien podría decirte `usa row = 2` o `usa Usuario = 'Carlos'` y va a obtener lo que buscas.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Con la misma idea, puedes extraer una serie de valores con un criterio de ordenación, y del mismo obtener luego el elemento que encaje en lo que necesitas.

```
CREATE TABLE Corredores (Row int, Usuario varchar (20), Lugar INT)
go
insert into Corredores (row, usuario, lugar)
values
(1,'Jose',4),
(2,'Carlos',5),
(3,'fulanit',7);
go
```

Y con una tabla derivada obtienes los 2 primeros, y con la salida, solo 1 ordenado del revés.

```
Select Top (1) d.[row]
             , d.usuario
             , d.lugar
       From (
              Select Top (2) corredores.[row]
                           , corredores.usuario
                           , corredores.lugar
                     From corredores
              Order By row Desc
            ) As d
Order By row Asc;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Puedes directamente usar [`ORDER BY`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#a-specifying-integer-constants-for-offset-and-fetch-values&DP-MVP-5002315) con `OFFSET` y `FETCH NEXT`:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Corredores
ORDER BY [Row] 
    OFFSET 1 ROWS
    FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
;
```